# How to output \wedge in R?

Tags: r, statistics

How can I output the wedge symbol in R?

For example if I wanted C ∧ W, I might use `$ \wedge $` in LaTeX. This is helpful when I have to use R to write a factor structure diagram.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wedge operator is apparently not included in the R `?plotmath` functionality. You can do this with a Unicode symbol, although it could conceivably be sensitive to the fonts available on your system/for a particular output format. (To figure out the appropriate code I did a web search for "Unicode wedge" and found e.g. the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_(symbol)); see also [here](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/%7Epaul/R/CM/AdobeSym.html))

```r
png("wedge.png")
plot(0:1,0:1, type="n", ann=FALSE,axes=FALSE)
text(0.5, 0.5, "A \u2227 B", cex=5)
dev.off()
```

[image: A wedge B]

If you want to go for the full-blown LaTeX solution you can use the `tikzDevice` package:

```r
library(tikzDevice)
tikz("wedge.tex", standAlone = TRUE)
plot(0:1,0:1, type="n", ann=FALSE,axes=FALSE)
text(0.5, 0.5, "$A \\wedge B$", cex=5)
dev.off()
system("pdflatex wedge; pdfcrop wedge.pdf; convert wedge-crop.pdf wedge2.png")
```

[image: A wedge B]